# merge two tables into one

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like join two tables into 1 table that has one common column and I need to try and avoid all duplicates.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking my friend.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the table structures that you are trying to merge. We could probably help you better then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this (new in SQL Server 2008): [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

> Performs insert, update, or delete
>   operations on a target table based on
>   the results of a join with a source
>   table. For example, you can
>   synchronize two tables by inserting,
>   updating, or deleting rows in one
>   table based on differences found in
>   the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a `SELECT DISTINCT` and a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a UNION and insert into the new table (note that you have to create the table first)

```
INSERT INTO NewTable

SELECT Column1
FROM FistTable

UNION 

SELECT Column2
FROM SecondTable
```

Comment: He stated there is only one column in common, this sounds more like a join than a union.

Comment: This would be my recommendation also.  I use these all the time at work to join common sets of data while avoiding duplicates.  Keep in mind that both selects will need the same number and types of columns if you go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition>
[WHEN MATCHED 
THEN <merge_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]
THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN <merge_ matched> ];
```